# Converting multiple datetime formats to single mysql datetime format

Tags: mysql

I hired a freelancer a little while ago to parse a website which had a datetime field. I had to put the project on the back burner shortly after the freelancer completed and now that I'm getting back into it, I've noticed some issues when I go into the MySQL database.

Specifically, there are two different datetime formats and I can't figure out how to update them into a unified MySQL sortable datetime field

```
Apr 8 - 2:23 AM                                  <- for current year updates
Tue, Dec 2, 2014 06:06:00 PM          <- for all previous year updates
2014-12-02 06:06:00PM                    <- desired format
```

I have a unique id in the table so I can select and update the formats easily. All "Apr 8 - 2:23 AM" format is < '6340' for example.  I also have created a "date_proper" column to update the current date column.

I just can't for the life of me figure out the correct code to update the different formats into the same unified format. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `str_to_date()` for this.  First, fix the `date_proper` column so it is a `datetime`.  Formats should be handled on input and output.  The proper storage for dates is using native formats:

```
alter table modify date_proper datetime;
```

Then you can update the values:

```
update t
    date_proper = (case when format < '6340'
                        then str_to_date(concat(year(now), ' ', col), '%Y %b %d - %h:%i %p'
                        else str_to_date(substr(col, 5), '%b %d, %Y %h:%i:%s %p'
                   end);
```