# Homogenize a field with different date formats in Mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, case

I am working with Mysql workbench.

I have a huge database in a csv, that contains among other things, 3 columns with different formats of dates.
To be able of loading this csv file into my database, I have to set the 3 date columns as text, otherwise, it doesn't upload them properly.
Here an example of my data:

```
inDate,                   outDAte
19-01-10,                 02-02-10
04-01-11 12:02,           2011-01-11 11:31
29-01-11 6:57,            29-03-2010
30-03-10,                 01-04-2010
2012-12-03 05:39:27.040,  12-12-12 17:04
2012-12-04 13:47:01.040,  29-11-12
```

I want to homogenize them and to make 2 columns of each one of those one only with "date" and other only with "time".

I have tried working with "regular expressions" and with "case".
When I used "reg expressions" gave me nulls and with "case" gave me "truncated incorrect value".

I have tried to find something similar situations in the web. I have found that people got similar issues but with two date formats not with so many different formats as I do:

- [Convert varchar column to date in mysql at database level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378003/convert-varchar-column-to-date-in-mysql-at-database-level)
- [Converting multiple datetime formats to single mysql datetime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729479/converting-multiple-datetime-formats-to-single-mysql-datetime-format)
- [Format date in SELECT * query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087363/format-date-in-select-query).

I am really new in this and I do not know how to write so many exceptions in mysql.

Comment: Is `02-02-10` in 2002?  Or is it in 2010?  That is, what should be done with ambiguous values?

Comment: yeah! that's also tricky!! fortunately I know that the data span is from 2010-2012. Otherwise not a chance to know it :(

Comment: So what is date is `10-11-12`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the CSV into a temporary table; massage the values in that table; finally copy to the 'real' table.

Have 2 columns in that table for each date; one for the raw value coming from the CSV; the other being a `DATETIME(3)` (or whatever the sanitized version will be).

Do one of these for each distinctly different format:

```
UPDATE tmp SET inDate = ...
           WHERE raw_inDate REGEXP '...';
```

The `WHERE` may need things like `AND LENGTH(inDate) = 8` and other ways to test other than REGEXP.

`SUBSTRING_INDEX(inDate, '-', ...)` may be a handy function for splitting up a date.

But, really, I would rather write the code in Perl or some other real programming language.

Comment: i have tried this already:     UPDATE datesDif 
SET inDate = (CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(inDate) = 8 
                          THEN STR_TO_DATE(inDate,'%Y-%m-%d')
                          ELSE STR_TO_DATE(inDate,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
                      END);  # gives error code 1411 incorrect dateme value

Comment: and this    UPDATE datesDif 
    set inDate = (CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@inDate, 1, 10) REGEXP '^([0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2})$' 
                 THEN STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(@inDate, 1, 10), '%d.%m.%Y') 
                 WHEN SUBSTRING(@inDate, 1, 10) REGEXP '^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})$'  
                 THEN DATE(@inDate) ELSE NULL END); # no error but gives nulls

Comment: No.  Do a separate `UPDATE` statement for each pattern of the date.  Don't try to build a big messy `CASE`.  Your samples seem to follow about 6 patterns.  Perhaps you have even more?